# Ordenar registros agrupados en mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tengo estas tablas en mysql

Tabla `articulo`

```
id_articulo     articulo       status  
   1             Agua           15  
   2             Hielo 05 kgs   11.5 
   3             Hielo 05 kgs   14.5
   4             Hielo 05 kgs   17
   5             Hielo 30 kgs   35
   6             Hielo 30 kgs   40
   7             Hielo 30 kgs   45
```

Tabla `precio`

```
id_articulo  precio     fecha
     1         15     2017-12-30
     2         11.5   2017-12-30
     3         14.5   2017-12-30
     4         17     2017-12-30
     5         35     2017-12-30
     6         40     2017-12-30
     7         45     2017-12-30
     2         25     2019-10-30
```

Lo que necesito es que ordene los registros dependiendo de la fecha pero tomando en cuenta que los artículos deben mostrarse de forma ascendente, por ejemplo si la fecha es **2019-10-30**

El resultado esperado sería el siguiente:

```
id_articulo     articulo       precio 
   1             Agua           15   
   3             Hielo 05 kgs   14.5
   4             Hielo 05 kgs   17
   2             Hielo 05 kgs   25
   5             Hielo 30 kgs   35
   6             Hielo 30 kgs   40
   7             Hielo 30 kgs   45
```

Solo tengo esto:

```
SELECT articulo.id_articulo, articulo, precio.precio 
FROM articulo
INNER JOIN precio 
ON articulo.id_articulo = precio.id_articulo 
WHERE '2019-10-30' >= fecha 
GROUP BY precio.id_articulo 
ORDER BY articulo, precio.precio ASC
```

Comment: No estoy seguro si entiendo pero has intentando un order by fecha? la tabla de lo que esperas no esta ordenada por fecha sino por articulo al parecer

Comment: @scorpio408 asi es ya que la lista de artículos debe de mostrarse de manera ascendente por el nombre y el precio debe ser el correspondiente a la ultima fecha menor a la fecha dada

Answer (score 0):

Mas o menos quedaría así pero noto un error el la tabla de precio, estas repitiendo una primary key que en ese caso es el "2" y te generara error  por la inconsistencia de los datos.
Pero mas o menos seria asi, si lo que buscas es acomodarlo por fecha.

```
select a.* from articulo as a inner join precio as p 
on  p.id_articulo = a.id_articulo
ORDER BY p.fecha ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

No es un problema de orden, sino algo más complejo. Lo esencial de tu pregunta esta en un comentario:

> el precio debe ser el correspondiente a la ultima fecha menor a la
>   fecha dada

Para saber este precio, por cada articulo, la consulta pasa por obtener la fecha más alta anterior a la fecha dada, el de dicha fecha será el precio al cual ir a buscar, algo así:

```
SELECT p.id_articulo,
       p.precio
       FROM precio p
       INNER JOIN (SELECT  id_articulo,
                           MAX(fecha) fecha
                           FROM precio 
                           WHERE '2019-10-30' >= fecha 
                           group by id_articulo
               ) m
               ON p.id_articulo = m.id_articulo
               AND p.fecha = m.fecha
```

Esta consulta, finalmente la integramos con los `articulos`:

```
   SELECT a.id_articulo, 
          a.articulo, 
          pmax.precio 
          FROM articulo a
          LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT p.id_articulo,
                        p.precio
                     FROM precio p
                     INNER JOIN (SELECT  id_articulo,
                                         MAX(fecha) fecha
                                         FROM precio 
                                         WHERE '2019-10-30' >= fecha 
                                         group by id_articulo
                             ) m
                             ON p.id_articulo = m.id_articulo
                             AND p.fecha = m.fecha
          ) pmax
          ON pmax.id_articulo = a.id_articulo
```

Nota: Esta consulta funciona bien siempre que tengas un único precio por fecha.